# Can't get HDMI out working on Lenovo G560

Tags: graphics, hdmi, monitor, displayport

Can I get **Dolby** To My PC but no on HDMI out please (our **DTS** whatever)
On Lenovo G560

`xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

`lspci -v`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 391e
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3920
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5050 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 38a5
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at d8406100 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 38aa
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d8405c00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 38af
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at d8400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: d7400000-d83fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0400000-00000000d13fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: d6400000-d73fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d1400000-00000000d23fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: d5400000-d63fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d2400000-00000000d33fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=0a, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: d4400000-d53fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d3400000-00000000d43fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 38b8
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at d8405800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=0b, subordinate=0b, sec-latency=32
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 38be
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 38c1
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    I/O ports at 5048 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 505c [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5040 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5058 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5020 [size=32]
    Memory at d8405000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 38bf
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at d8406000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=32]

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 38c0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at d8404000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 30a1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at d6400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 392e
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at d2410000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d2400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Expansion ROM at d2420000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 392b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 392b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 392b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 392b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 392b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 392b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
```

Comment: What graphics are you using? Please add more information, and the output of `lpsci -v` and `xrandr` to your question.

Comment: Screen minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767

Comment: 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9

Comment: like this ?????

Comment: That's better :-) - but you still need the output of `lspci -v` to show the graphics card + drivers.

Comment: OMG this very long comand i copy all of this to paste is ? (because if think you now this is big command)

Comment: I Add It :-) this is all the command so i think this can give you the information